# L1 vs. L2 Robustness?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function, distance

I am very new to ML so I apologize in advance if the answer to my question is very obvious. I am reading about performance measures and how the L1 norm is more robust than the L2 norm. In other words, the 1-norm is more resistant to outliers as it only sums the absolute distances compared to the 2-norm where distances are squared. But what about the fact that in the 2-norm, the square root is taken on the sum of the squares yielding a smaller result than the L1 norm for the same set of distances (no matter the outliers)? Shouldn't this slow response to big values be interpreted as robustness? Or do I have the wrong idea about the norm definitions or the definition of robustness?

Comment: What is the context when you say: "the fact that in the 2-norm, the square root is taken on the sum of the squares"? What loss function do you refer to? With OLS, for instance, the sum of squared residuals is minimized, which makes "outliers" prone to having a huge impact.

Comment: I would ask this question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it seems you are after understanding different properties of these regularizes

Comment: Is the context linear regression?

Comment: This was related to linear regression and cost.  I figured out my mistake.  I was comparing the L1 to L2 when I should have been looking at how the L2 norm changes with respect to itself (not with respect to L1) when outliers are introduced compared to L1 to itself under the same change.